# Flutter: Declare variable of type Widget which implements a given Interface

Tags: flutter, dart, types, interface

I have an interface defining some methods that should be implemented by the State of Statefulwidgets.

```
abstract class ValidatedSettings {
  bool hasMadeChanges();
  void save();
  bool validate();
}

class SomeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const SomeWidget(super.key);
  State<SomeWidgetState> createState () => SomeWidgetState();
}

class SomeWidgetState extends State<SomeWidget> with ValidatedSettings {
  @override
  bool validate () => true;
 
  ...
}
```

How can I declare a List of Widgets that implement this interface? In another class, I want to do something like this:

```
class AnotherWidget extends StatelessWidget {
 
  final List<ValidatedSettings> widgets;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: widgets
    );
  }
  ...
}
```

Obviously, the above doesnt work since ValidatedSettings is not a Widget. But I need a way to make sure that AnotherWidget only takes widgets which implement the ValidatedSettings interface.

How could I achieve something like this?